# ¿Cómo hacer GROUP BY en consulta Linq-To-Sql?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Construí esta consulta y me devuelve algunos registros repetidos, ¿cómo podría hacer para que me agrupara por el campo ***sd.IdSolicitudDetalle***? … y así  eliminar los registros que no necesito.

Mi Código:

```
   public List<DetalleSolicitudModel> DetalleSolicitudModel(int idSolicitud)
        {
           var lst = (from s in db.A_CC_Solicitud
                   join sd in db.A_CC_SolicitudDetalle on s.IdSolicitud equals sd.IdSolicitud
                   join sdp in db.A_CC_SolicitudDetalle_Proveedor on sd.IdSolicitudDetalle equals sdp.IdSolicitudDetalle
                   where s.IdSolicitud == idSolicitud
                   select new DetalleSolicitudModel
                   {
                       IdSolicitud = s.IdSolicitud,
                       IdEstado = s.IdEstado,
                       Titulo = s.Titulo,
                       FechaSolicitud = s.FechaSolicitud,
                       FechaVigencia = s.FechaVigencia,
                       FechaVigenciaProveedor = s.FechaVigenciaProveedor,
                       **IdSolicitudDetalle = sd.IdSolicitudDetalle,**
                       IdArticulo = sd.IdArticulo,
                       Nombre = sd.Nombre,
                       Descripcion = sd.Descripcion,
                       Comentario = sd.Comentario,
                       Cantidad = sd.Cantidad,
                       ImporteVenta = sd.ImporteVenta,
                       ImporteTotal = sd.ImporteVenta,
                       FechaModifica = (DateTime)sd.FechaModifica,
                       IdOfertaProveedor = sdp.IdOfertaProveedor,
                       IdProveedor = sdp.IdProveedor,
                       Proveedor = sdp.IdProveedor,
                       EstadoProveedor = sdp.EstadoProveedor
                   }).ToList();

            return lst;
        }
```

Comment: Realmente estas usando linq-to-sql o estas usando Entity Framework ? diseñas las relaciones en un .dbml

Comment: Estoy usando Entity FrameWork ..en i proyecto tengo un .edmx

Comment: Pero entonces eso no es linq to sql, seria entity framework usando database first. Necesitas definir en el linq los `join` desde el modelo las entidades no tienes propiedades de navegacion entre ellas?

Comment: Estas seguro que entiendes el concepto de un `GROUP BY`? si estas queriendo una lista de `detalles` como vas agrupar por un `id` del `detalle`, eso no tiene sentido. Tienes que haber un agrupador que una los items que lo repiten, un Id de Detalle es individual para cada detalle, no se puede agrupar.

Comment: Bueno...si puedo hacer q el campo IdSolicitudDetalle no se repita  voy a obtener la lista que deseo...seria algo como un Distinct ..y tienes razon el Group By lo que hace es agrupar los elementos repetido en listas anidadas

Comment: Si obtienes una lista de detalles, como harias que el id de esos detalles no se repitan? se trata de la key del detalle es imposible que varios tengan el mismo valor para agrupar. Quizas deberias pensar mejor que info necesitas obtener en realidad

Comment: Alli estan los registros  ...simplemente que la seleccion devuelve 9 lineas y deberian ser 3 solamente

Comment: pregunta, no me queda claro si quieres un group o un distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar el GroupBy se hace de la siguiente forma

```csharp
   lst.GroupBy(x => x.IdSolicitudDetalle /* Agrupador */,
               (key, group) => group.FirstOrDefault()) /* Seleccionas el primero para evitar duplicados */
   /* .ToList() */;
```

El resultado de esta operación es un *IEnumerable* entonces es aceptado como retorno para *List*, o en su caso se puede ejecutar **.ToList()** al final del **GroupBy**

Comment: Solo le explicaste como hacer un group by sin analizar lo que esta planteando, eso lo podria haber realizado con solo leer la documentacion de linq

Answer (score 0):

Solucione tomando en cuenta la respuesta de Rigoberto Ramirez Cruz

```
 public IEnumerable<DetalleSolicitudModel> DetalleSolicitudModel(int idSolicitud)
        {
           var lst = (from s in db.A_CC_Solicitud
                   join sd in db.A_CC_SolicitudDetalle on s.IdSolicitud equals sd.IdSolicitud
                   join sdp in db.A_CC_SolicitudDetalle_Proveedor on sd.IdSolicitudDetalle equals sdp.IdSolicitudDetalle
                   where s.IdSolicitud == idSolicitud
                   select new DetalleSolicitudModel
                   {
                       IdSolicitud = s.IdSolicitud,
                       IdEstado = s.IdEstado,
                       Titulo = s.Titulo,
                       FechaSolicitud = s.FechaSolicitud,
                       FechaVigencia = s.FechaVigencia,
                       FechaVigenciaProveedor = s.FechaVigenciaProveedor,
                       IdSolicitudDetalle = sd.IdSolicitudDetalle,
                       IdArticulo = sd.IdArticulo,
                       Nombre = sd.Nombre,
                       Descripcion = sd.Descripcion,
                       Comentario = sd.Comentario,
                       Cantidad = sd.Cantidad,
                       ImporteVenta = sd.ImporteVenta,
                       ImporteTotal = sd.ImporteVenta,
                       FechaModifica = (DateTime)sd.FechaModifica,
                       IdOfertaProveedor = sdp.IdOfertaProveedor,
                       IdProveedor = sdp.IdProveedor,
                       Proveedor = sdp.IdProveedor,
                       EstadoProveedor = sdp.EstadoProveedor
                   }).ToList();

           var list = lst.GroupBy(x => x.IdSolicitudDetalle ,(key, group) => group.FirstOrDefault());

           return list;
        }
```

Comment: Esa no es una solucion correcta, los id de detalle no se repiten si estas listando detalles. Cada grupo que se defina tendra un unico item por lo cual no agrupo nada. Sigues sin entender que es un group by.